# Export and Import a list of graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, export, import

I want to export a list of graphs that come as output to my program. However, I tried exporting all the graphs as graphs using Map and an Export statement with "graph.gml" statement, but got an error. I also tried exporting the list as a .dat file, but then when I import the list of graphs, I can't get it back to the "nice" pictorial form. Does anyone have any suggestions? I imagine there is a simple solution and I'm probably just implementing my attempts wrong.

Comment: "and I'm probably just implementing my attempts wrong" <-- you're more likely to get a useful answer if you describe what you tried

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `graphs` is your list of graphs.

```
names = Table["graph" <> ToString@i <> ".gml", {i, Length@graphs}]
MapThread[Export, {names, graphs}]
```